# how to update 2 databases from each other?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a small accounting program which I built using c#.net , and I used sqlite database cause it's serverless database. 
Now this program installed at my father's store(PC), and he have a laptop which he carry to the home and he want to install it on the laptop too cause sometimes he want to do some work at home.
So I want to do something to update this 2 databases to be the same.
I dont want to copy paste the database file cause i dont want to lose any data.
I want to check the changes at the 2 databases and update them if anychanges.

my question is how could i do that ?

note:  the 2 computers will be connected on the local network.

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to make a mirroring algorithm or whatever. Maybe it has came the time to go for a true RDBMS, which usually implement mirroring by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need ADO.Net Sync services , see [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608)

Comment: thanks for this resource , but do you have an example or tutorial about how to do it ?